# App crashes when sending push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, pushwoosh

I have pushwoosh integrated in my app and everything works fine if the app is active or in the background. However, if I send a notification while the app is not in memory it'll crash. The launch screen comes up, but then it shuts down immediately. If you try to open the app manually, it'll crash from then on. It has to be reinstalled completely.
As, this bug only happens when the app is inactive, I have no way to debug the problem. Anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Apparently you need to keep the app in memory from the example you've (imaginably) illustrated.

Comment: Can you show me code in your didReceiveRemoteNotification in your AppDelegate.m ??

Comment: Can we see the crash report from the device?

Comment: I have no crash report, because the app is not in the app store yet

Comment: Are you 100% sure the app is terminated, because the situation you have described is impossible unless its a voip push (only voip pushes get delivered to a terminated app, all other types of pushes do not, therefore sending a push to a terminated app cannot run the app therefore it can't crash)

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification is only called when the app is memory. My problem happens when the app is *not* in memory

Comment: Yes, I'm 100% sure. When user presses on push notification the app launches.

Comment: The situation you have described just cannot happen. Therefore I do not know what to say. Once the app has got into the state where it crashes when opening, have you tried launching it using Xcode instead of launching it manually?

Comment: Launching it from xcode would cause the app to reinstall, right?

Comment: It suddenly started to work on it's own, after I tried to attach the debugger. I don't really understand what happened, but thanks for the help guys ;)